# How to check fps consistency for an ip camera

Tags: streaming, camera, ip-camera, rtsp, cctv

> Blockquote

How can i check the number of frames captured by an ip camera?

Background:
I'm not much experienced in IP cameras, but my work right now is to fix an fps inconsistency of a grabber module (C++ module that reads stream from ip camera). So i need to know if the camera actually produces a steady frame rate. My first goal here would be to find out who's fault really is (camera or module).

The grabber module generates an fps lower than the required fps but there's a lot of inconsistency in the frame rate. For example, when setting up the camera in 20 fps, the module grabs images at an average of 19.5 fps. But at some instances the fps is as low as 7 and sometimes it peaks up to 23. That's the similar case for 10 fps as well.